# How to use openemr Rest API of MedMaster?

Tags: php, android, api, rest

I am new to PHP and REST api. I want to use OpenEMR API in android application but I don't know where to start. I would be really obliged if anyone can provide me the steps and if possible an example of using this API. I have successfully installed the web based OpenEMR from

http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_Downloads

Openemr Rest api Source:

https://github.com/oemr501c3/openemr-api

Please reply as soon as possible because it's the first step to complete my project.

Comment: Show some effort, really there are no tutorials about this?

Comment: @KonradKokosa Well Sir, I did on my level but i didnt got any so my last option is to approach this wonderful place.